# Why does Internet Explorer 9 render Arial stronger than other browsers?

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9

For some reason IE9 renders Arial font bolder than other browsers such as: IE7, IE8, Chrome, and Firefox. I have looked for the reason in the CSS but couldn't find anything wrong.

Another thing that happened is that I had word-spacing of 1 or 2 pixels in most of my website, but IE9 showed it too wide, so I made conditional css for it with normal word-spacing.

You can see the difference in the attached screenshot, and also find it in this temporary link:
http://pat.co.il/shirg/matanuziel.com/
[image: chrome on the left, ie9 on the right]

Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is it just on your site that this issue occurs or all sites using the arial font?

Comment: good point. I tried looking at cnn.com with some browsers but all looks the same. That's why I think it has something to do with my website.

Comment: Yes, they've changed the rendering engine in IE 9 to use DirectWrite, just like Firefox 4+. I don't care for it; it makes the text all blurry-looking. Other people seem excited about it, like the entire DirectWrite team. It's not a problem with your site or the CSS, it's a problem with the eyes of a large influential group of developers.

Comment: But I should add that I don't think you should try and "fix" it. The people who use IE 9 and other browsers that have adopted DirectWrite as their text rendering engine are *used* to this behavior—it seems normal to them because all of their other webpages render the same way. And given that everyone knows [that webpages don't need to look exactly the same in all browsers](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/), it's much easier and much less painful to just let your text render the way the browser wants to render it.

Comment: @CodyGray is absolutely right. As I mentioned before, it's such a trivial issue. Thank your lucky stars that *this* is what you're concerned about and not something far more ridiculous and intractable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The problem is the browser**, not your site.

Internet Explorer 9 uses sub-pixel positioned ClearType to render text by using DirectWrite. This can cause rendering differences compared to other browsers and is expected behavior. It can cause text to blur slightly more, just as you're seeing.

---

As a side note, you should consider using [TypeKit](http://typekit.com) if you want to use non-standard fonts and have them render (resonably) well for all users. Note that there will still be minor rendering differences across browsers, probably on the same order of magnitude as what you're experiencing here.

And as Alan stated, using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) is a good idea.

Comment: Like having to develop hacks for nice CSS3 feautres to meet a req that it should work best in IE6? :/

Comment: @fabianhjr exactly. Or worse.

Comment: Is there any solution for this? like Cufon (I've never used it) ?

Comment: @ShirGans Look at the 3rd para about TypeKit.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/). I don't know if it'll address your specific issues, but I've found that it's a nice starting point.

Comment: thanks. it looks as a good starting point. I added it to check, but it didn't help for the font issue. I nothing will help I'll try to get deeper into it.

Comment: @ShirGans This is not the problem, as it turns out. But it remains a good suggestion nonetheless.