# IE9: wrong rendering of Arial (bolder)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've tested my page in Chrome, FF and IE8 and all the browser render the text this way:

[image]

It is defined like:

```
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
font-size: 0.75em;  
font-weight: bold;
```

I've tried declaring Arial in different ways, using px instead of em and also define the weight in number (600, 800)... But IE9 still renders is "bolder" than the other browsers:

[image]

Any help? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Internet Explorer 9 render Arial stronger than other browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676336/why-does-internet-explorer-9-render-arial-stronger-than-other-browsers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to weigh in, you could place a meta tag into your HTML as a quick workaround, which will tell IE9 to emulate IE8, bringing back the original rendering.

To do this, place `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />` in your  section.

However this will come at the expense of other IE9 features you may need, like the better HTML5 and CSS3 support.

Comment: That answer was really helpful +1

Answer (score 6):

You might have a different problem, since you said you tried a weight of `600`, but generally, when you tell IE 9 to render `Arial` as bold, what you end up seeing is not `Arial`, but `Arial Black`. This switch will happen for `font-weight`s of `800` and `900`.

To have a bold `Arial` in IE 9  without switching to `Arial Black`, use...

```css
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 0.75em;  
font-weight: 700;
```

This should also address the same issue in Firefox.

Comment: My goodness - this one had me stumped. I couldn't see why the font was so much wider in IE... Why they would do this I don't understand...  If I want Arial Black I can ask for it!
Are there any other font switches the browser just decides to do?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I elaborated a bit in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12184181/3283. IE also seems to have some combinations hard coded. Incidentally, since Chrome switched away from GDI and over to DirectWrite for font rendering on Windows, I've had to give up (for now) on using Arial Black because of a Windows oddment that goes back to a Windows XP Service Pack which results in Arial Black being rendered as Arial Black Italic. Still a problem in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 5):

This question has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676336/why-does-internet-explorer-9-render-arial-stronger-than-other-browsers) on StackOverflow before.
It's a browser issue, IE9 renders fonts different. It uses a ClearType technique called DirectWrite.

In my personal opinion, this isn't a big problem. Websites never look absolutly similiar in every browser. If it really bothers you, it's possible to add IE-Hacks (e.g. force the browser to use IE8-rendering) but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: [http://www.dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/](http://www.dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/)

Comment: i'm not trying to accompish a "everywhere looks the same" effect, but bolder texts give wider content that in my case doesn't simply look different, it is plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

IE in general tends to give me headaches.
What I would do is use conditional CSS and remove the bold from the IE css

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ie9.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

And then define it like this

```
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
font-size: 0.75em;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue when I accidentally set the `font-weight:bold` on the body tag. For some reason IE9 rendered all my Arial text bolder than other browsers.